# Can be the non shared services used in symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, service

I already read this [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/shared.html), about non shared service, so my question, can this be used in symfony 2.7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, this feature was introduced in 2.8.

So, in 2.7, [you can deal with scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html) to have several instances of the same service across your application.

To get the same behavior as `shared` (a new instance for each service call), use:

```
your_service:
    # ...
    scope: prototype
```

Answer (score 0):

From the cookbook that you linked.

> 2.8 The shared setting was introduced in Symfony 2.8. Prior to Symfony 2.8, you had to use the prototype scope.

There is a combo with versions just below the main title. Select "2.8 version" and check yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I see the combo, but I saw that maybe could be introduced in some recent version of 2.7.